# Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 Summary from DLLs

Tags: c#, xna, ide, visual-studio-2013, xna-4.0

I have been working with a DLL which contains some classes, and one of the classes has some constants. I wrote `Summary` for every one of these constants and these summaries appears as "tooltips" when I want to use the constants inside the DLL.
However, when I access these constants from the main project which is referencing this DLL, I don't see any `Summary` in the tooltip.

Does anyone know a solution for this problem? Everything is declared with a `public` access modifier. But MVS2013 does not cache these `Summaries`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To see the summaries outside of the project you need to build the XML documentation file. Go to the project settings and select the **Build** section. At the bottom you'll see the "Output" options, and there will be a checkbox for **XML documentation file** make sure it's checked (in both debug and release modes).

If you're deploying the assembly by hand to other projects you'll need to make sure you copy the documentation XML file as well.